# Blazor Global exception Handling Duplication

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to follow MS article for Global exception handling in Blazor explained in this link

[Handle errors in ASP.NET Core Blazor apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#global-exception-handling-1)

I was expecting to see the error exception in index page content, but instead  the results came in 2 separated sections:

[image: Doubling of the View]

Any ideas how to show the error to be within the content of index page ?

#### Code

###### ErrorCasCading component

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@inject ILogger<Error> Logger

<CascadingValue Value=this>
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

<LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <h1>Sorry, An error happen</h1>
    <p>An error happen, please try again.</p>
</LayoutView>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    private string MyProperty;
    public void ProcessError(Exception ex)
    {
        MyProperty = "An error happen, please try again";
        Logger.LogError("Error:ProcessError - Type: {Type} Message: {Message}",
            ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

##### App.Razor

````
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <ErrorCasCading>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly"
                AdditionalAssemblies="new[] {
                              typeof(Login).Assembly
                              }">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        <h1>Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</h1>
                        <p>You may want to try logging in (as someone with the necessary authorization).</p>
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </ErrorCasCading>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>```
````

Comment: Remove your `<LayoutView />` code snippet in the global error handler razor file. Blazor can only render one layout at a time.

Comment: even if we removed the <LayoutView /> the result will not appear in the main content

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Use a boolean for displaying the message when an error occurs.

Comment: we did but as i explained the error not show inside the main content of html it shows in separate content that why the page shows like that, i want way to inject the error in main content, we tried to follow same concept of   <NotFound> or <NotAuthorized> that shown the error inside the main content but we coudn't